# RadioButtonList SelectedIndexchanged Event not firing If The Text is Very Long

Tags: vb.net, webforms, radiobuttonlist, selectedindexchanged

Hello please i have a little problem or should i say an enormous problem that has been given me alot of headache. I am coding an Online Examination Application in vb.net. I notice that if the text of a radio button is very long the SelectedIndexchanged event those not fire. Don't know why that's the case. But when i reduced the text length the event fires as expected. I need the event to fire because that's how i am saving the selected answer choice of a participant taking the exam

```
  Dim i As Integer = CType(Session("i"), Integer)

    Dim index As Integer = rad.SelectedIndex

    ''here am checking if the person has already answered the question

    ''the person has already answered the question so projct answer back

    Dim myAns As New SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, Integer)


    ''am saving back the answer that the idiot has just answerd 
    Dim xml_serializer As New  _
       XmlSerializer(GetType(SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, Integer)))
    Using string_reader As New StringReader(Session("SVEnglish"))
        myAns = DirectCast(xml_serializer.Deserialize(string_reader),  _
            SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
    End Using


    If myAns.ContainsKey(i) Then
        myAns.Remove(i)
        myAns.Add(i, index)
    Else
        myAns.Add(i, index)
    End If

    ''saving back to session

    Dim savedAns As String = ""
    Dim xml_serializer2 As New  _
        XmlSerializer(GetType(SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, Integer)))
    Try
        Using string_writer As New StringWriter()
            xml_serializer.Serialize(string_writer, myAns)
            savedAns = string_writer.ToString
            Session("SVEnglish") = savedAns
            string_writer.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try




    Dim selectAnswers As New SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, String)

    Dim xml_serializerAnswers As New  _
         XmlSerializer(GetType(SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, String)))
    Using string_reader As New StringReader(Session("SelAnswerEnglish"))
        selectAnswers = DirectCast(xml_serializerAnswers.Deserialize(string_reader),  _
                SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, String))
    End Using
    If selectAnswers.ContainsKey(i) Then
        selectAnswers.Remove(i)
        selectAnswers.Add(i, rad.SelectedItem.Text)

    Else
        selectAnswers.Add(i, rad.SelectedItem.Text)
    End If



    Dim selAns2 As String = ""

    Dim xml_serializerSavedAnswers As New  _
            XmlSerializer(GetType(SerializableDictionary(Of Integer, String)))
    Try
        Using string_writer As New StringWriter()
            xml_serializerSavedAnswers.Serialize(string_writer, selectAnswers)
            selAns2 = string_writer.ToString
            Session("SelAnswerEnglish") = selAns2
            string_writer.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Stop
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the code am running in the selectedindexchanged subroutine. The radiobuttonlist is populated from the database. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Use a TextBox or Label for each radio button, you just track what was selected from radio button .. the text is just a text near radio button :)

Comment: If the event is not firing, then the code you have shown is not running and cannot help find the problem. Some helpful information might be: Is this winforms or WPF? Is that a Telerik RAD control or standard winforms control? How long is the text exactly? Did you narrow it down to a specific number of characters? And what font size?

Comment: @Crowcoder It is a web form project and the code runs. The selectedindexChanged event only fires if the text is not long longer than a 100 characters

Comment: @James thank you, my point is, the code in the event is not causing the problem. The code you have shown is irrelevant and just misdirects the investigation. I'll see if I can recreate the issue.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the problem. Are you sure the event doesn't fire, or does it error somewhere in the event?

Comment: Do you have Dropbox? OneDrive? GitHub?

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks alot for all your effort and help. I have traced the problem. The issue is not from the length of the text in the dropdownlist. I was saving the questions in a session variable and as i was debugging the application the session variable was not been cleared. So for a question that is already present in the session variable  the selectedIndexchanged event those not fire for that question. Thanks it had nothing to do with the length of text the RadiobuttonList